# SQL Server Chain Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, say Table 1 as below:

```
A   B   Year    Revenue
100 200 2012    100000
100 300 2015    100001
200 100 2012    100000
200 300 2012    22222
200 300 2015    22222
300 100 2012    122
300 200 2012    23444
```

Now, I want a Table 2 as below without using any stored procedure, just need to use a SELECT query in SQL Server:

```
A   B   Year    Revenue
100 200 2012    100000
200 100 2012    100000
100 300 2015    100001
300 100 2012    122
200 300 2012    22222
200 300 2015    22222
300 200 2012    23444
```

Comment: Please explain the logic so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want pairs of A/B values to appear together.  You can do this with `ORDER BY` and some logic for bringing them together:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN A < B THEN A ELSE B END),
         (CASE WHEN A < B THEN B ELSE A END),
         A;
```